# pywintypes.error: - Code that print the printer jobs

Tags: python, list, jobs, printers

Python code that print the printer job.
I get the error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Eden\Downloads\102.py", line 29, in <module>
    print_job_checker()
  File "C:\Users\Eden\Downloads\102.py", line 15, in print_job_checker
    phandle = win32print.OpenPrinter(name)
pywintypes.error: (1801, 'OpenPrinter', 'The printer name is invalid.')
```

Code is:

```
import time
import win32print

def print_job_checker():
"""
Prints out all jobs in the print queue every 5 seconds
"""
jobs = [1]
while jobs:
    jobs = []
    for p in win32print.EnumPrinters(win32print.PRINTER_ENUM_LOCAL,
                                     None, 1):
        flags, desc, name, comment = p

        phandle = win32print.OpenPrinter(name)
        print_jobs = win32print.EnumJobs(phandle, 0, -1, 1)
        if print_jobs:
            jobs.extend(list(print_jobs))
        for job in print_jobs:
            print "printer name => " + name
            document = job["pDocument"]
            print "Document name => " + document
        win32print.ClosePrinter(phandle)

    time.sleep(5)
print "No more jobs!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
print_job_checker()
```

The source is: http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2013/12/19/pywin32-monitor-print-queue/

Comment: Can we see how flags, desc, name, comment are defined? Can you print them before the OpenPrinter call?

Comment: Im using 'cmd' - python 102.py